# SELECT query count not outputting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

I am trying to `COUNT` the number of id records I have in my users table `WHERE` in group 3, 4, and 5. However when I try to output that number, nothing outputs. I do not have any errors.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$total_members_query = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id)FROM users WHERE 'group' IN (3, 4 ,5)")
    or die ("Total Members query failed: %s\n".($total_members_query->error));
    $total_members_query->execute();
    $total_members_query->bind_result($total_members);
    $numrows_members = $total_members_query->num_rows();
    if($numrows_members > 0){

    while($members_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_members_query)){
?>
        <div class="member_summary_statistics">
        <div class="member_summary_category_title">League Statistics</div>
        <div id="member_summary_member_count">Members in your league: <?php echo $total_members; } } ?></div>
```

Comment: You have straight quotes around `group`, where you intend backticks.  Or, better yet, change the name of the column.  Don't use reserved words as column names.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't help though. Still nothing is outputting.

Comment: does the table have data for those specific groups?

Comment: Yes, there are records for it.

Comment: have you tried without a `where` clause?just to check

Comment: How would I structure it then or are you saying to `SELECT` *` users for now to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Replace single qoute ' using `, 'group' means a string and `group` means a column so replace your sql

```
SELECT COUNT(id)FROM users WHERE 'group' IN (3, 4 ,5)
```

by

```
SELECT COUNT(id)FROM users WHERE `group` IN (3, 4 ,5)
```

Comment: can u give a link at sqlfiddle.com